# How to Format a Reply to a Question's Response?

Tags: discussion, answers, markdown

When someone answers a question, I often find I need to reply to the answer. When I attempt to cite the answer, Stack Overflow does not honor some of the formatting (such as CR/LFs entered with SHIFT-ENTER). See, for example, [NSFileManager and NSDirectoryEnumerator Crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252354/iphone-nsfilemanager-nsdirectoryenumerator-crash).

The mini-help below the text box does not offer assistance, and there is no link to the full help. The FAQ is also missing an explanation.

In general, how does one format a reply? In particular, How does one preserve CR/LF?

Comment: Comments don't support line breaks. But since they're directly attached to the post in question, it's generally unnecessary to quote the section to which you are replying. People can figure it out from context.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have that much more to add, it's okay to augment someone else's answer via your own answer, but don't be shy about giving them credit (*and linking to their post, remember there can be lots of pages of answers*).